# Working with mathematical models, HELP.

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, mathematical-modeling

I'm currently doing a lot of self study with mathematics.
I live in The Netherlands and hope to be admitted to Leiden University somewhere in 2016.

Now, I have encountered a problem in my workbook which I can't seem to be able to solve, even after I looked at the worked solutions..

So I made a picture of it, and hope some of you can help me pinpoint what knowledge I'm missing and what I'm not getting. (I will translate the problem completely below.)

[image]

Translation : **5.4 Working with mathematical models.**

The sheet of paper ABCD of 20cm by 30cm is folded in such a way that point D is laying on side AB of the sheet of paper.
The point where D touches AB is called D' and the fold line which is created is called PQ, look at the figure on the right.

a* (You can ignore this one)

b  Take AP = 5 cm
   why is D'P = 15 cm?
 Show that this is true with a calculation and
   that in this case AD' is about 14.1 cm.

**The Ans. to b.** 
Take AP = 5.
D'P = AD' - AP = 20 - 5 = 15 ©
Pythagoras:  AP ²  + AD' ²  = D'P ² 
-------------- 25 + AD' = 225 
 
-------------- AD' ²  = 200 
-------------- AD' = √200 ≈ 14.1 cm.
**Now, what do I not understand.**
I placed a copyright sign to show what I'm talking about 
This part is conflicting with my understanding of Pythagoras..
How can AD'(20) be longer than the hypothenuse? shouldn't it be as follows: 
D'P = AD' + AP ?  What's going on? With the rest of it I'm oké.
c Take AP = 8 cm © and calculate AD' in mm's accurate.
We ask ourselves how long should we make AP such that AP = AD'
Put AP = x cm  ©

**Ans. to c.**
Take AP = 8 ©.
D'P = AD' - AP = 20 - 8 = 12 ©
Pythagoras:  AP ²  + AD' ²  = D'P ² 
-------------- 64 + AD' = 114 
 
-------------- AD' ²  = 80 
-------------- AD' = √80 ≈ 8.9 cm.
 
**Now, what do I not understand.**
The overall character of the problem asked to solve..
So you take AP = 8 cm, AP has to equal AD', but, AP is also equal to x??
Could someone walk me through the reasoning process? 
problems d, e and f build further upon b and c.

Hope this is clear enough.
Thanks, Bowser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first : Note that $AD'\not=20$ and that $PD'=PD=AD-AP=20-5$.

For the second : Note that $AP\not=AD'$ and that $PD'=PD=AD-AP=20-8$.

The point is to see $PD'=PD=AD-AP$ and to consider a right triangle $APD'$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me a bunch!

Comment: Funny how it seems so simple after you see it.. The beauty of reasoning right there.